# Either vision for or vision on

Tags: prepositions

Which one of the two prepositions should be used in the following sentence

The company released a statement on Saturday paying tribute to its founder, praising his philanthropic efforts and his vision **on/for** healthcare.

I think **on** is correct because we usually say **his ideas on sth sth...** and here also vision is somewhat related to ideas.

Comment: Why do you think only one is possible? You can often use multiple prepositions.

Answer (score 1):

I think "vision on" could be used by analogy with "ideas on", as you point out. That might apply where vision is more a matter of perception.

However, if the leader's vision had more to do with controlling or influencing what would become of health care or his company's work in health care, it might be "vision for", by analogy with "plans for".

Google ngram viewer shows "vision for" is a bit more common:
[Google ngram viewer "vision for, vision on"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vision%20for%2Cvision%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)